# No detection of Nexus 5X in Visual Studio for debugging xamarin.forms

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-debugging

I cannot debbug a Xamarin.Forms application on my Nexus 5X :

- In Android SDK, I have downloaded the Google USB Driver
- I have activated the dubbuging mode on my device
- I have tried to disconnect and connect my device
- I have tried to restart VS
- I have tried to reinstall the Nexus 5X USB driver found here : https://androidmtk.com/download-google-nexus-usb-drivers

It used to work though !

I do not understand what is happening...

Comment: What is the output when you run `adb devices` in the command prompt?

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand : adb is an unknown command...

Comment: By the way, I have discovered something new : when I start VS after connecting my device, Xamarin Android Player (which is deprecated) appears for debbuging instead of my device. I will try to unistall Xamarin Android Player...

Comment: Xamarin Android Player and Oracle Virtual Box uninstalled. Do not work

Comment: Understood : I clicked on "Open Android adb command prompt".
I executed adb devices : it says
List of devices attached
00d3.............e7 device

Comment: what was the output?

Comment: List of devices attached 00.....................e7 device

Comment: When I click on "Start" I get :
3>Please select a valid device before running the application.
3>------ Deploy started: Project: Almicantarat.Droid, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
3>Error: Cancelled
========== Build: 2 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: Goto Build menu/Configuration manager... and make sure the deploy is checked for your Android project. It looks like the app is not deployed to the device

Answer (score 1):

First, I have the same device and am able to side-load on it just fine. Things I would check would be the Output and Build windows of Visual Studio for any errors.

Also go into the Android project properties and make sure at least **armeabi-v7a** and **x86** are checked.

Finally, maker sure the Nexus 5X is in the Camera (PTP) USB mode. I do not have the 5X with me right now but some device do not have the Camera (PTP) mode, in that case, just keep changing the modes until you find one that works.

Once I have the settings correct I sometimes have to restart Visual Studio, set the Android project to the startup project (even if it seems to already be set that way), and unplug and re-plug the device a few times. Once the device shows up in the file explorer as a drive, Visual Studio is usually able to detect it a few seconds later.

*Edit: You may also open the SDK Manager and make sure you installed/updated the **Google USB Driver**

Comment: all supported architectures are checked

Comment: Nexus 5X was in MTP mode and now in PTP mode

Comment: I restarted VS, It says "Start". Output is: 2>Please select a valid device before running the application.
2>------ Deploy started: Project: Almicantarat.Droid, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
2>Error: Cancelled
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: When I unplug and replug the device, VS proposes only virtual device for debbuging

Comment: @Pierre-LouisDeschamps Make sure you right-clicked the Android project and set it as the startup project. Then try unplugging the device and plugging it back in. Does it show up as a file explorer drive?

Comment: The android project is set as the startup project. I tried to unplug and replug. By default it was in MTP mode. I set it in PTP mode before plugging. It is detected in the explorer: I can browse the device.

Comment: @Pierre-LouisDeschamps Damn... I am at a loss then, hopefully someone can suggest something else. Sorry I could not be more helpful.

Comment: Damn... that il what I was thinking :-) Thank you for your help

Comment: @Pierre-LouisDeschamps One more thing I have run into, though not sure why this would have suddenly changed on you, but after enabling developer mode on the phone, I also had to check USB debugging, within the developer settings menu. Good luck and let us know what finally fixes it if you find out

Comment: Yes it was in USB debbuging mode. I unactivated it and activated it back: unefficient...

Answer (score 0):

> Project: Almicantarat.Droid, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------ 3>Error: Cancelled ========== Build: 2 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ========== ========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

It looks like the project is not enable to deploy on the device.
Goto Build/Configuration manager... and make sure the deploy is checked for your Android project.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be: Active solution config: Debug, Active solution ptf: Any CPU, A.Droid: debug any CPU **Build** **Deploy**, A.XF configuration Debug PTF any CPU **Build**

Comment: moreover, If I connect and disconnect my device, I can check with "adb devices" that it connects and disconnects. If I connect it before I start VS, I get "Start" in the list of devices, if I connect it after I start VS, VS does not detect my device...